# Getting the value of an element with XSLT then removing it

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using XSLT to clean up some InDesign-related XML for use in other systems. I need to be able to grab the value from tags nested in the text body then remove them.

Specifically, the headline and byline come embedded in the text body. I need to be able to extract these and put them in header tags - I'm able to do that, but I can't seem to get them out of the body while I'm at it.

Here's my (simplified) XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<k4Export xmlns="http://www.vjoon.com/K4Export/1.4.2">  
    <publication>
        <id>107233722</id>
        <name>NGM</name>
        <origin>origin</origin>
        <issue>
            <article>
                <textObjects>
                    <textObject>
                        <text>
                            <inlineTag name="Story">
                                <inlineTag name="body">
                                    <inlineTag name="headline">The Headline</inlineTag> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                                    consectetur adipiscing elit. <em>Vivamus mollis</em> ligula quis mi
                                     blandit interdum. In rutrum imperdiet suscipit. Fusce interdum, 
                                    sem id scelerisque molestie, purus ligula fringilla sapien, nec
                                     auctor velit eros eget felis. Duis eu tellus purus. Donec id viverra
                                     neque.</inlineTag>

                                    <inlineTag name="body">Donec nec nulla neque, sit amet placerat 
                                        elit. Nulla pulvinar elit sapien. Donec venenatis, arcu sed
                                         pellentesque ultrices, neque mi sollicitudin elit, nec fermentum
                                         eros nibh aliquam leo. Nam lectus neque, dapibus in scelerisque
                                         in, fermentum nec ipsum.</inlineTag>

                                    <inlineTag name="body">Sed sed <strong>congue</strong> neque. Nulla
                                     nec ipsum vitae lacus consectetur convallis sed et nulla. Integer
                                     posuere viverra felis, at pulvinar risus scelerisque ac. Aliquam a
                                     orci ac est iaculis porta. Duis sollicitudin lectus sit amet velit
                                     condimentum lobortis.
                                    <inlineTag name="byline">-John Doe</inlineTag></inlineTag></inlineTag>
                        </text>
                    </textObject>
                </textObjects>
            </article>
        </issue>
    </publication>
</k4Export>
```

And here's the XSLT I'm using to transform. I'm able to get the headline and byline into the header, but I'm not able to get it out of the content. I'm an XSLT noob so any advice will be appreciated. The textObject elements come spread out all over the XML document, so I'm intentionally using very general XPath selectors to get to them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:default="http://www.vjoon.com/K4Export/1.4.2" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="2.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="default">

    <!-- Output Content -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Sample</title>
            </head>

            <body>

                <!-- Headline-->
                <xsl:variable name="headlines" select="//default:inlineTag[@name='headline']" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$headlines">
                        <xsl:for-each select="$headlines">
                            <h1 class="headline"><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></h1>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <h1 class="headline">Headline Absent</h1>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                <!-- Bylines -->
                <xsl:variable name="bylines" select="//default:inlineTag[@name='byline']" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$bylines">
                        <xsl:for-each select="$bylines">
                            <h2 class="byline"><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></h2>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <h2 class="byline">Byline Absent</h2>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                <div id="content">

                    <!-- body -->
                    <xsl:variable name="bodies" select="//default:inlineTag[@name='body']" />
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$bodies">
                            <xsl:for-each select="$bodies">
                                <p><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></p>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>

                </div>

            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @user646151: What would be the exact desired output for this input sample?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an easy and obvious solution. Discover templates, discover XSLT. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this (note that the `<xsl:for-each>` is now replaced by `<xsl:apply-templates>` and there are different templates for processing the `inlineTag` elements with different values of their `name` attribute. In particular, empty-bodied-templates do not copy the node they match to the output). Other than this, I haven't made any attempt to otherwise re-factor or improve your code -- it has big potential for improvement.

**The result now doesn't contain either the headline or byline**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet      xmlns:default="http://www.vjoon.com/K4Export/1.4.2"      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"      version="2.0"     exclude-result-prefixes="default">
    <!-- Output Content -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Sample</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <!-- Headline-->
                <xsl:variable name="headlines" select="//default:inlineTag[@name='headline']" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$headlines">
                        <xsl:for-each select="$headlines">
                            <h1 class="headline">
                                <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                            </h1>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <h1 class="headline">Headline Absent</h1>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <!-- Bylines -->
                <xsl:variable name="bylines" select="//default:inlineTag[@name='byline']" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$bylines">
                        <xsl:for-each select="$bylines">
                            <h2 class="byline">
                                <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                            </h2>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <h2 class="byline">Byline Absent</h2>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <div id="content">
                    <!-- body -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//default:inlineTag[@name='body']" />
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="default:inlineTag[@name='body']">
      <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template priority="10" match=
    "default:inlineTag[@name='byline' or @name='headline']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```